# Ask for or ask about?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, adverbs

please help me this.

1. The reason I'm phoning you to ask about her address.
2. The reason I'm phoning you to ask for her address.
3. The reason I'm phoning you to ask her address.
   Which one is correct?
   Thank you very much!

Comment: Please do not just post three sentences and ask "which is correct"

Comment: You want to be given the address, not told something 'about' it. You are asking the other person, not the address.

Comment: @JamesK  What shall I ask?

Answer (score 1):

#2 is basically correct, but you need to add "is"

> The reason I'm phoning you is to ask for her address.

The word "is" is required because you started with "The reason".
It is grammatically correct (but a little rude) to say:

> I'm phoning you, to ask for her address.

You could also say:

> The reason I'm phoning you is to ask you for her address.

But I don't really like repeating the word "you" with the contraction "**I'm**". So I would probably either:

Remove the first you:

> The reason I'm phoning, is to ask you for her address.

Or expand the contraction (sounds more formal)

> The reason I am phoning you, is to ask you for her address.

Finally "her" is impersonal if I knew the name I would use it:

> The reason I'm phoning, is to ask you for Jane's address.

Comment: I got it. thank you very much!